# What can I use to easily program the Back-End for ReactJS?

Tags: reactjs

There seem to be so many options and I'm quite unsure which to go for. I need something that can be used to insert and read just basic data in/out a database in real time. What would be the best solutions?

Comment: This question is too broad and opinion based for Stack Overflow. You'll likely get downvotes and/or have the question closed, just a heads up. There's heaps of information out there on this and it depends a lot on your requirements, have a look around and do some research. If you have *specific* questions about any of the options then that might be something SO can help with.

Comment: Have a look at: https://github.com/gothinkster/realworld which has an API to match any supported front-end with any supported backend for a single demo project. One specific backend which also subscribes to this "any frontend" idea is: https://github.com/feathersjs/feathers notably for React: https://github.com/feathersjs-ecosystem/feathers-chat-react just worked when I tested it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ReactJS` is just front end library which can be linked to any API sever (built with any language Java/.Net, PHP, NodeJS).

`ReactJS` has no particular requirements and this is the reason of being so famous. The only things that matters are

- Which language you know and have expertise to code the backend.
- Application requirements according to business logic
- Budget limitation to have a backend application developed and then finally ofcourse, hosting cost.

It's that simple to plan and finalize.

You might see number of suggestions or recommendations, but there is no where on `ReactJS` website where it says, that these languages are supported or recommended as backed application for `ReactJS`.

All it needs is to have an API server (services) where our `ReactJS` application can communicate (to fetch or push data).

If you know `JAVA` then go ahead and create API server, but if you know PHP, then you can use PHP to create an API services. However, if you know `Node.js` then you can go ahead and write backend API server/services in it. The only thing `Node.js` is known is that it is specially built to create API services.

**What if you don't know any language (to code Backend)?**

No worries, if you are newbie you can use https://firebase.google.com, which gives following benefits:

- Less learning curve, no much effort required to learn a full language and then its security, then its maintainance, and then hosting. No such thing
- Use `Firebase` api and use its database to save and retrieve data.
- More interesting thing is, that it's free for testing and for small level application
- No need to worry about server security and other stuff etc.

Comment: That's a bit too broad since I don't know any back-end language and I don't want to invest a lot of time in it. Still, thanks for answering

Comment: updated last answer

Comment: That's nice of you. I've been struggling to make Firebase work for since yesterday, because I was getting a bunch of errors and even though I installed all the dependencies, Firebase still couldn't install. So that's not an option anymore :/ That's actually the main reason for me puting up this question on Stack.

Comment: I will recommend you to go with `Firebase` as it is very effective option. If you are getting errors then post that error message question on `Stackoverflow.com` instead of accepting defeat in first attempt. What is the guarantee that you will not get any errors or trouble with any other language or platform :)

Comment: That's actually really motivating :D I was kinda desperate since I even wrote on the forums for the dependencies that had errors and got now answer, so I just wanted to move on and I did. I did the stuff I needed in localstorage. But, when you wrote me 'instead of accepting defeat' I remembered this pic, as I have it on my desktop https://prntscr.com/jeuutd Thank you! =]

Comment: I've opened a question by the way > https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50217389/grpc-error-while-installing-firebase-for-react

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using meteor.
https://www.meteor.com
And mongoDB as the database.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest `node.js`. Also, for any decently sized application, you will need predictable state management on the client side, which is exactly what `redux` intends to solve.

Look for tutorials and examples online (there are plenty).